# Get first value in a CSV field from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database in SQL Server 2018. Unfortunately there is a multiselect column that stores values as a CSV string in a column.

The following values can be seen:

```
Value1
Value1,Value2
Value1,Value2,Value3
....
```

I have tried the following approach

```
select SUBSTRING(t.FIELD, 0,charindex(',',t.FIELD)) as first_value 
from TABLE t
```

However this returns the first value only when there is  comma, and not when there is only a single value

Currently the query returns

```
NULL
Value1
Value1
```

I want the query to return

```
Value1
Value1
Value1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick. You can find your version by running `SELECT @@VERSION` on your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily fix your logic by adding a comma to the field for the call to `charindex()`:

```
select left(t.FIELD, charindex(',', t.FIELD + ',') - 1) as first_value
```

Note that I also replaced `substr()` with `left()` because that is more concise.

Comment: Hello This mostly works however returns the value and leads a trailing comma
i.e.

Value1
Value1,
Value1,

Comment: @Pythonuser . . . Just subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage JSON_VALUE to get the first value from comma separated list of values, like given below:

```sql
DECLARE @t table(cval VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t values
('Value1'),
('Value1,Value2'),
('Value1,Value2,Value3');

--Convert the comma separated list into JSON Array and pick the first value
SELECT JSON_VALUE(
        CONCAT('["',replace(cval,',','","'),'"]'),'$[0]') as firstValue
        FROM @T
```

One more approach of using xml.

```
SELECT  
CAST(concat('<root><v>',replace(cval,',','</v><v>'),'</v></root>') AS xml).value('(/root/v)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM @T
```

```
+------------+
| firstValue |
+------------+
| Value1     |
| Value1     |
| Value1     |
+------------+
```